# Can I see how many collectibles I've gotten in a level without exiting to the level select screen?

Tags: lara-croft-go

I'm trying to quickly clean up levels that I missed collectibles on so I can get the platinum, but I can't figure out how to see if I've gotten all the collectibles for a level without exiting to the Level Select screen (which takes more time than I'd like it to).

Is there a way to view a level's collectible completion *while still in the level*?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not - there is no way to view collectible while in a level.